# What does the field "0x671xxxx" in the AST structure mean?

Tags: clang, llvm, abstract-syntax-tree

What does the field "0x671xxxx" in the AST structure mean?What APIs can I get to this field?(The example program is as follows. Thanks:)

```
    t12.b = 3;


    |-BinaryOperator 0x6712768 <line:22:2, col:10> 'int' '='
    | |-MemberExpr 0x6712718 <col:2, col:6> 'int' lvalue .b 0x6711e00
    | | `-DeclRefExpr 0x67126f8 <col:2> 'struct test1':'struct test1' lvalue Var 0x6712260 't12' 'struct test1':'struct test1'
    | `-IntegerLiteral 0x6712748 <col:10> 'int' 3
```

Comment: Probably address of the tree node in memory. Having that can be convenient when using a debugger.

Comment: thanks，how can I get this pointer?

Comment: From which starting point? What do you have?